# gWidgetstcltk on Mac - native look and feel

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit, gwidgets

I've been making a GUI for an R package with gWidgets and gWidgetstcltk and have just finished it, on Windows it's looks fairly normal - Windows 7 style look of buttons etc, but on the Mac it does not look native - it's all grey and square in it's style. Is there something I can do on my Macintosh to enable a native look - once when I built the package in RStudio it appeared native but after that it never did it again (I made no settings change etc) - I've made no explicit effort to change how it looks on any system since I'm not sure where I would even start - hence the question. I'm using R 3.x.x presently. I have XQuartz on my mac.

Thanks,

B. Ward

Comment: Sounds like you have tcltk linked to the X11 libraries for tk and not the aqua ones.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check this or alter this to link to the aqua ones. The reason I'm using gWidgets and gWidgets tcltk is the code you write in R for it is toolkit independent but tcltk works on most computer's I've worked on out of the box compared to RGtk.

Comment: If I recall you can compile R and set the location of the tcltk libraries at that point. RGtk2 is unfortunately really problematic on the mac right now, so that is no help for wider distribution.